# xCode 5.02 Signing Identities Distribution list not Found

Tags: ios, certificate, xcode5

The xCode detect (Distribution)Provisionning Profile that was affected to my application Production certificate.
When i see the list on preference->Account->View Details, i don't found it.

[image: Not List Found]
[image]
What the problem can be??

Comment: Have you tried to refresh with button in left below?

Comment: yes i have tried this, and it worked in other mac, i have juste add new provision profil for this mac assigned to the same certificate

Comment: Maybe Mac, that you are using isn't enabled for development?

Comment: yes it's enabled for developement, i just test it on my ipad with developement certificate, and it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had only to export the certificate key *.p12 from mac who i had generate the original certif, and to reimport it on the new one....
thanks for all